# How can I hide some elements from a select list?

Tags: javascript, web

I am new to programming and I would like to know how to hide some options from a select control I have...
I am going to explain the thing: So, i have two select controls.. according to the option from the select number 1, I want to hide some items from the second select, but I don't know how to do it, I was trying with some jQuery .hide but it is not working... Hope you can help me... 
Thank you

Comment: can you paste some code what you have tried?

Comment: We won't spoonfeed everything. You need to tell us what you have tried. Probably spend time and create a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: I was trying somthing like this:

if($("#APU").val("1")){
 $("#celda option[value = 'raven']").hide();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this gives you an idea, since you didn't post any code.

HTML

```
<select id="selectA">
  <option value="">Select Fruit or Veg</option>
  <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
  <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
</select>

<select id="selectB">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="apple" data-type="fruit">apple</option>
  <option value="orange" data-type="fruit">orange</option>
  <option value="carrot" data-type="vegetable">carrot</option>
  <option value="tomato" data-type="vegetable">tomato</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var selectA = document.querySelector('#selectA')
var selectB = document.querySelector('#selectB')

selectA.addEventListener('change', event => {
  var type = event.target.value;

  [].slice.call(selectB.querySelectorAll('option'))
    .forEach(el => {
      el.style.display = (el.dataset.type === type ? 'block' : 'none')
    })
})
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hw76aLqv/1/**

Comment: Thank you.. I needed an example to guide myself !!

Comment: Hi! I have tried your answer with my code, which helped me a lot... but it isn't working in IE... Could it be another alternative to make it work on there? Thank you !!

Comment: @AsLop might be the arrow functions, but here's a fiddle using jquery for cross browser compatibility https://jsfiddle.net/b61as914/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 if($("#APU").val("1")) {
    $("#celda option[value = 'raven']").wrap('<span>')
}
```

To show again, just find that option(not span) and

`$("#celda option[value = 'raven']").unwrap()`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps . Although the jQuery function is pretty lengthy but This way you will be able to get what is actually happening . After selecting an option from first select element , do a check whether id is 'selectA' or not .

Take the selected option as an object in the variable OPTIONS.
and then go to the next select Element using .next() function .

There use a loop which will go through all the child elements of select element . 
after that I am doing a check . If the data-type of the child element is not equal to options.val() hide the child element using .hide()

Here is the code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).attr('id')=='selectFirst'){
        var options = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var nextSelect = $('select').next();

        nextSelect.children().each(function(){
            child  = $(this);
            if(child.attr('data-type') != options.val()){
                child.hide();
            }

        });

    }
});
```